# How to use end() in jQuery with pure javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to return an element to the first element in the chain, as long as I have a code like this

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item-child">list item 1</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 2</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

then I want to activate a class called active, only in the first element and other elements there will be no class called active, and the elements below will move up to replace the first element while the first element will come back down the chain.

this code using jQuery looks like this

```js
$(".items > .item-child:gt(0)").removeClass("active");

setInterval(function() {
  $(".items > .item-child:first").removeClass("active");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".items > .item-child:first")
      .next()
      .addClass("active")
      .end()
      .appendTo(".items")
  }, 4000)
}, 10000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item-child">list item 1</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 2</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

this is the code I generated while looking for a solution

```js
document.querySelector('.items > .item-child:not(:first-child)').classList.remove('active')
setInterval(function() {
  var otif = document.querySelectorAll('.items > .item-child:first-child');
  otif.forEach(function(e) {
    e.classList.remove('active');
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.items > .item-child:first-child').forEach((e) => {
      e.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
      console.log(e.nextElementSibling)
    })
  }, 4000)
}, 10000)
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item-child">list item 1</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 2</li>
  <li class="item-child">list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since native methods aren't chainable there really is no `end()` equivalent

Comment: Just an FYI - there is a code formatting button in left menu of the snippets editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the previous question code and realised what you intended to do and put together the following demo using vanilla javascript. Admittedly i jazzed it up a little with random images but I think essentially it does what you were doing with jquery originally

```js
const _INTERVAL=5;
        
( function( i ){

  // find the parent element - UL
  let ul=document.querySelector('ul.items');

  (function(){
    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 * i );
    // remove the active class from ALL li elements
    ul.querySelectorAll('li.active').forEach( li => { li.classList.remove('active') } );

    // take the element node and the text node and move to the bottom of the list
    ul.append( ul.childNodes[0] );
    ul.append( ul.childNodes[1] );

    // add the `active` class to the first element 
    ul.firstElementChild.classList.add('active');
  })();
})( _INTERVAL );
```

```css
ul.items{ list-style:none!important; }
.items li{ margin:0.5rem auto }

.active{ color:red; }
.active:after{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:6rem;
  width:12rem;
  background-image:url( //static.thenounproject.com/png/438141-200.png );
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

  animation: shake 0.25s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
}
li > img{ border-radius:0.5rem; border:1px solid gray; padding:0.25rem;}
.active > img{ box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);animation: shake 1.25s cubic-bezier(.4,.08,.29,.97) both;}


@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
  transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  20%, 80% {
  transform: translate3d(2px, -5px, 0) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70% {
  transform: translate3d(-4px, 5px, 0) rotate(5deg);
  }
  40%, 60% {
  transform: translate3d(4px, -5px, 0) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class='items'>
  <li class='active'><img src='//placem.at/things?w=200&h=100&random=1&txt=1' /></li>
  <li><img src='//placem.at/things?w=200&random=2&h=100&txt=2' /></li>
  <li><img src='//placem.at/things?w=200&random=3&h=100&txt=3' /></li>
  <li><img src='//placem.at/things?w=200&random=4&h=100&txt=4' /></li>
  <li><img src='//placem.at/things?w=200&random=5&h=100&txt=5' /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow, that's what I meant, apparently playing logic for append and children to move the element selector. thank you very much friends you really helped me after 2 days looking for a way out of this problem.

Comment: I'm glad that I have been able to help you solve your issue